# Canvas Usage in Angular2

Tags: canvas, angular

I am adding the canvas dynamically and I have to draw something on that canvas.
How to access the canvas

```
<canvas id=\"myCanvas\" class='myCanvas' #myCanvas width=\"100\" height=\"100\">
```

I am adding this dynamically using innerHTML on the required div

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-view',
        template: `
           <div [innerHTML]="{{str}}"></div>
    `

        })

        export class countryOverviewComponent implements ngOnInit(
               private str="";
               ngOnInit() {
                 this.str="<canvas id=\"myCanvas\" class='myCanvas' #myCanvas width=\"100\" height=\"100\">";
                 this.getCanvas();
           }
           getCanvas(){
              //I have to get the canvas here.
         }
        )
```

Comment: That's not what I needed

Answer (score 1):

When adding Angular2 specific syntax using `[innerHTML]`, Angular2 just passes the string as-is and doesn't process it in any way.

If you want to add it dynamically, wrap it in a component and use [`ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html) do add the component dynamically.

For an example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)